# Cannot run npm install in docker on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, docker, build

I am trying to build a dockerfile on my Raspberry Pi 4, running arm64 Ubuntu 20.04. The same dockerfile runs fine on my main computer. The dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:12 as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY .client/package.json .
COPY .package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
...
```

Upon building this file I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  29.35MB
Step 1/12 : FROM node:12 as builder
 ---> 70b24a2d7b95
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2ab48332f35b
Step 3/12 : COPY .client/package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d7009f4cfa0b
Step 4/12 : COPY .client/package-lock.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 59d4f21519ed
Step 5/12 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 84f62d84dcbe
Aborted (core dumped)
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 134
```

The error code of 134 refers to running out of memory on the host, but I have checked both memory and storage and there seems to be plenty of space left. What could be the issue? Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, completely different image, also npm install step explodes like for OP with same error.
What's more interesting, I also have access to what's supposed to be the final image from same build process but built by sbd else, on dockerhub, and that image won't run either, with same error code. Can find absolutely no other logs for the dead container anywhere.

Comment: I have opened an issue for it on the Node github page and the issue seems to be resolved now, although I haven't tried it ever since :) https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33244

Comment: Also, this seems to be an ubuntu 2004 issue currently. After downgrading to 1804 the problem doesnt exist anymore.